# Why doesn't titlescreen display anything?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame,sys
pygame.init()

size = (425,550)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

lightcyan = (191,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

titlefont = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri",36)
subtitlefont = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri",24)

def title():
    titlescreenAlpha = 0

    centeredText = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    centeredText = centeredText.convert()
    centeredText.set_alpha(0)

    titlescreen = pygame.display.set_mode(size).convert()
    titlescreen.set_alpha(titlescreenAlpha)
    nowiseeText = titlefont.render("NOW I SEE",1,black)
    centeredText.blit(nowiseeText,(0,0))
    nowiseeTextRect = nowiseeText.get_rect()
    nowiseeTextRect.center = (size[0]/2,225)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        if titlescreenAlpha < 255:
            titlescreenAlpha += 1
            titlescreen.set_alpha(titlescreenAlpha)
        print(titlescreenAlpha)

        screen.fill(lightcyan)
        titlescreen.blit(nowiseeText,nowiseeTextRect)
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

title()
```

I'm attempting to make a title sequence for an e-spread about optics. This is all I have so far.

Whenever I run it, `titlescreenAlpha` increases by 1 until it reaches 255, but `titlescreen.set_alpha(titlescreenAlpha)` doesn't seem to be working.

Why can I only see stuff on screen?

Comment: You have syntax errors that do not allow the script to run. `import pygame.init()` should not be on the same line as import. Same goes for `screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)` and `black = (0,0,0)`. Also`nowIseeAlpha` is not defined.

Comment: @siavashk Oops, typos. I fixed them

Comment: why do you use `set_mode` three times ? `set_mode` is not function to create surface - you have `pygame.Surface()` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mess in code. You use `set_mode` three times but it is use to create window, not surfaces. Pygame has [pygame.Surface()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) to create surface.

---

Main problem is `alpha`.

PyGame has two types of alpha:

- per pixel alpha - every pixel has own alpha values (ie. image with transparent background)
- full surface alpha - pygame uses the same alpha for all pixels (ie. to smoothly show/hide image)

PyGame can't use both in one surface - see [set_alpha](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_alpha)

You have to create text with background and then you can use `set_alpha`

```
import pygame
import sys

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

LIGHTCYAN = (191, 255, 255)
BLACK     = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE     = (255, 255, 255)

SIZE = (425, 550)

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

# empty

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

def title():

    # init
    pygame.init()

    # create window
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

    # create fonts
    title_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri", 36)
    subtitle_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri", 24)

    # render surface with text (and background) and center on screen
    text = title_font.render("NOW I SEE", True, BLACK, LIGHTCYAN) # WHITE)
    text = text.convert()
    text_rect = text.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)

    text_alpha = 0

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

        # change "full surface alpha"
        if text_alpha < 255:
            text_alpha += 1
            text.set_alpha(text_alpha)
        print(text_alpha)

        # draw everything on `screen`
        screen.fill(LIGHTCYAN)
        screen.blit(text, text_rect)
        pygame.display.flip()

        pygame.time.wait(10)

# --- main ---

title()
```

---

**EDIT:** more complex version :)

```
import pygame
import sys

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

LIGHTCYAN = (191, 255, 255)
BLACK     = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE     = (255, 255, 255)

SIZE = (425, 550)

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

# empty

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

def title(message, screen, scree_rect):

    # create fonts
    title_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri", 36)
    subtitle_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri", 24)

    # render surface with text (and background) and center on screen
    text = title_font.render(message, True, BLACK, LIGHTCYAN) # WHITE)
    text = text.convert()
    text_rect = text.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)

    text_alpha = 0

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return False # to skip rest of program
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    return True
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    return True

        # change "full surface alpha"
        if text_alpha < 255:
            text_alpha += 1
            text.set_alpha(text_alpha)
        print(text_alpha)

        # draw everything on `screen`
        screen.fill(LIGHTCYAN)
        screen.blit(text, text_rect)
        pygame.display.flip()

        pygame.time.wait(10)

# --- main ---

# init

pygame.init()

# create window

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

# many scenes

result = title("CLICK MOUSE", screen, screen_rect)

if result: # skip if pygame.QUIT
    result = title("OR PRESS ESC", screen, screen_rect)

if result: # skip if pygame.QUIT
    result = title("NOW I SEE", screen, screen_rect)

if result: # skip if pygame.QUIT
    result = title("HELLO WORLD", screen, screen_rect)

if result: # skip if pygame.QUIT
    result = title("BYE, BYE", screen, screen_rect)

# quit

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: thank you so much! I've only learned Python for 2 months, and haven't gotten to alphas yet.

Comment: What does center=screen_rect.center do?

Comment: Pygame uses [pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to keep position and size (and check collisions). It has properties `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` and also others like `center` (`(width//2, height//2)`) so you can get center point or set center point (and move object). Code `text_rect = text.get_rect(center=screen_rect.center)` works like two lines `text_rect = text.get_rect()` and `text_rect.center = screen_rect.center` so it moves `text` to center of `screen`